# Wordpress Category archive: Separate loops for separate post types

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, archive

I have two custom post types for my site, but am using the same Categories/Tags for both.

I am trying to create a category.php page that will allow me to show all items within that category, but in two separate areas, one for each type.

I can get the first post type to display in the main loop, but how can I structure a second loop to display only the posts in the second type that are of that category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use to instances of WP_Query and in args section, for both sections have set post_type= for the desired one.

```
<?php

//general code to get the current category id

$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat' => $cat_id,

);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

     echo get_the_title();
     echo get_the_excerpt();


    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 



//for second loop of second post type

$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat' => $cat_id,   
);
$the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 ); 
if ( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : 
while ( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : $the_query1->the_post();

     echo get_the_title();
     echo get_the_excerpt();


    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```